# Can't upload " *.pot " file to the SharePoint document library via SP GUI

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Every time I try to upload the file with pot extension, I receive this error message.

The file name is invalid or the file is empty. A file name cannot contain any of the following characters: \ / : * ? " < > | # { } % ~ &

I also verified and made sure that pot file is not blocked in Central Admin.

Comment: Maybe an obvious question, but are you sure it's an issue with the extension and not the file name itself?

Comment: the pot template represents PowerPoint presentations with version 97-2003 version. I just simpley can't upload files with pot extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*" is a special character in SharePoint so you file CANNOT contain that character.  Try renaming the file.

Comment: No, the doesn't have * character. I just generlize that files with Pot extensions are not uploaded

Comment: @Free Styler  what is the file name you are trying to upload?

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue when uploading an empty file. That might be the case if you just want to test something.